# What is meant by 'relation/relationship' in Predicate Logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$ Int(x) = $ "x is an integer."

**Int** is a unary predicate symbol which I understand to mean that **Int** takes one input x.

I have also seen **Int** described as a unary relation.

Would the relation be between the domain, say all numbers and {0, 1} (0 = false, 1 = true)?

Example:
5, would map to 1 (true)
5.1, would map to 0 (false)

Comment: For a given interpretation $I$, the "meaning" of an unary predicate $P$ is the subset $P^I$ of the domain of the interpretation such that $P$ is true of the elements of the subset. So, in a sense, yes: if $a \in P^I$, then $P(a)$ is True and False otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can interpret predicates (as distinct from the symbols representing them that the other answer covers) as maps from elements of the domain of discourse to the set $\{0,1\}$. Saying that a predicate is a "unary" relation is to treat it as a special case that maps single elements of the domain - more general relations take pairs, triples or larger $n$-tuples of elements as inputs, but their outputs are always the binary set $\{0,1\}$ or equivalently $\{false, true\}$